# Fabric Twitter Login module does not work correctly with Android 4.x devices

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter-fabric

I am currently supporting Twitter login in my Android application.
While the twitter Login runs successfully on Android 5.x devices, I am running into an issue on Android 4.x devices only.

On android 4.x devices, after entering the twitter credentials(username and passwd) on the authentication screen, it does not return back to my application. 
In fact when I press the "Authorize app" button on the authentication screen, nothing happens! However when the Twitter client application (available on Google play store) is installed on the device, the authentication works fine and returns back to my app once the authentication is done.

Having debugged a bit, I feel this could be an issue with the WebView Client used in the "com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthActivity" within the Twitter core module.
(the shouldOverrideUrl() method checking for the callBack URL is never called for Android 4.x devices. The same is called correctly for android 5.x devices).

Stuck at this issue for couple of days now. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Kindly let me know in case any additional details are required for debugging.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you completely read this [article](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/authentication.html)? One of the important moments here - handle result in **onActivityResult**.

Comment: @Alexander, yes done that! As I've mentioned it works fine for Android 5.x. The implementation is as per the Fabric article